# Play sound in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have the following code in myScene.h :

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

And this code in the touchBegin method:

```
[self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"fire.m4a" waitForCompletion:NO]];
```

The audio file is in the main folder. When I run the app and touch the app is shut down and I get the following error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Missing Resource', reason: 'Resource fire.m4a cannont be found in the main bundle'
```

I thought this is the way to play audio in Sprite Kit but I must be doing something wrong..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Delete the file from your project and add it again.
Remember to select

```
Copy items into destination group...
```

And select your project as a target (not test).

Comment: Wow that actually worked! Thanks! Will accept your answer as soon as I can. (there's a time limit)